# $\sum_i x_i^2 +\sum_i\sum_{i\neq j}B_{ij}x_i x_j \geq 0$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, polynomials, summation, positive-semidefinite

Let $0\leq B_{ij}\leq 1$. Is it true that $$\sum_i x_i^2 +\sum_i\sum_{i\neq j}B_{ij}x_i x_j \geq 0$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$? In other words, is the matrix $I+B$ (with $B_{ii}=0$) positive semidefinite?

It is true when $B_{ij}=1$ for $i\neq j$, since
$$
\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2=\sum_i x_i^2 +\sum_i\sum_{i\neq j}x_i x_j \geq 0
$$
but I would like to have a more general result.

Comment: Rephrased: "Is $x^t (I + A)x \ge 0$ for $x \in S^n$, where all entries of $A$ are between $0$ and $1$, and $a_{ii} = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Over what range of $x$? If all of the $x_i$ are non-negative then it's trivially true...

Comment: The magic phrase is 'positive definite' (and 'positive semidefinite') - look for information on positive definite matrices and quadratic forms and you should be able to find useful information.

Comment: @JohnHughes: Yes and all entries on the diagonal of $A$ are 0.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I know about positive definiteness. I guess my question is: "Is $I+B$ positive semidefinite?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
$$
B =  
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1  \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\
x =  
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $x^t (I+B) x = -1$, if I've calculated correctly.

Comment: Each $B_{ij}$ must be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry 'bout that!

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample!

Comment: Sure. Sorry for swapping the sign condition on $x$ and $A$ earlier.